# Dual monitors - I'm almost there, but my mouse cant cross the divide

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, ati, multiple-monitors

I'm having a very strange problem with the open-source radeon drivers. In a valiant attempt to set up dual monitors on ubuntu, I have

A) Used to open source to no avail (Mirrored Displays)

B) Upgraded to 12.04 with no difference

C) Tried using fglrx, where stranger bugs abound (One screen white, the other perfectly fine!)

D) Made many attempts to purge fglrx, one of which resulted in

```
Could not write bytes: Broken Pipe
* Starting the WinBind daemon [OK]
saned disabled, edit etc/default/saned
* Starting anac cron          [OK]
* Stopping anac cron          [OK]
* Checking Battery State...
```

The odd thing is, it's a desktop. Shutdown (not startup!) hung on this message until I forced it.

E) Finally, fglrx is purgred! Magically, this seems to fix all my previous problem with the open-source driver. I can drag windows across! No more mirrored displays! But there is still one problem...

Even though I can drag *windows* across (I know this because the window appears partway between screens), *I cannot drag my mouse across.* It gets stuck on the edge of the window (all of the edges, in fact) even though the window makes it partway across. Am i not just pushing hard enough? Or are there larger things in play here? And most importantly, *how do I fix the problem?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure you've probably already tried this, but I'll throw it out there just in case:

Go to System Settings --> Displays and make sure 'Sticky edges' is turned off.

Comment: Oh my god, I am such a moron. Internet high-five. (Can't mark this as correct for a few minutes.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Displays. If in Displays, Monitor 1 is on the left and Monitor 2 is on the right, it helps if they are actually placed in the same manner. Otherwise, the mouse gets confused. Or so i think. My 2 cents.

Comment: Yes, placing the on-screen monitors in the correct right-relative-to-left positions solved this for me, in Ubuntu 22.04 startup disk version.